# React PropTypes - OR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

For this code:

```
const FirstComponentPropTypes = {
   foo: PropTypes.any,
};

const SecondComponentPropTypes = {
   bar: PropTypes.any,
};

...

function MyComponent({ foo, bar }) {
   if (foo) {
     return <FirstComponent foo={foo} />;
   } else if (bar) {
     return <SecondComponent bar={bar} />;
   }
   
   throw new Error("Invalid props.");
}
```

In order to set the `propTypes` of `MyComponent`, is it possible to do something like:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = FirstComponentPropTypes | SecondComponentPropTypes;
```

?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you do inside MyComponent with the two props? Is there any conditional logic that involves the two props?

Comment: Why are you doing this else you can use prop type inside your single component but you are making your code more difficult yourself

Comment: @lifeisfoo basically, `MyComponent` is a "generic" component which renders A if `foo` is present or B if `bar` is present.

Comment: @BuildThough I think is the cleanest way to handle my use case. I am rendering a huge amount of components `FirstComponent` or `SecondComponent` depending on some data. So, basically, if I directly pass the data as property to a "generic" component `MyComponent` I am skipping some spaghetti code and reducing the complexity of my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out:

> MyComponent is a "generic" component which renders A if foo is present or B if bar is present.

And it's definition is `function MyComponent({ foo, bar }) { ... }`

In order to avoid complex solutions, I suggest you to move the conditional logic outside of `MyComponent`. In this way you will need a single propType definition for MyComponent without duplicating the propType definitions of the other two components. The type your component will check is [`element`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes), a common type shared by all React's elements.

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
    elementToRender: PropTypes.element
};
```

So you need to adapt your component definition:

```
function MyComponent({ elementToRender }) { ... }
```

And the way it is used:

```
const getComponentToRender = (foo, bar) => {
   if (foo) {
     return <FirstComponent foo={foo} />;
   } else if (bar) {
     return <SecondComponent bar={bar} />;
   } else {
     return null;
   }
}

const element = getComponentToRender(foo, bar)
```

Your jsx:

```
{!element && <YourErrorComponent />}
{element && <MyComponent elementToRender={element} />}
```

You can always put your conditional logic inside the component without using a constant or variable, if you want.

### Benefits

The biggest benefit of this approach is that your `MyComponent` doesn't need to know anything about yours `FirstComponent` or `SecondComponent` types. And you can always choose to use another component to pass to `MyComponent` without changing it.

Moreover, you have a single point in the code where types are defined and you don't have any dependencies between them.

Also, you are not getting props in one point and then using them in a condition far away from it.

### A final consideration

To keep you code easy to read, I suggest you to avoid using a specific prop for an element. Use `props.children` instead:

```
    {element && <MyComponent>{element}</MyComponent>}
```

This is a more *React-ish* (*natural*) way to show a component inside another one: the `children` props exists to this purpose.

Moreover, you can put (again) a fallback logic inside MyComponent:

```
function MyComponent({ children }) {
    if (children) {
        return <div className="container">{children}</div>
    }
    
    return <p>children is missing</>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `|` as in you want to take the union of the two sets? You can just merge the two objects with something like Object.assign():

```
const FirstComponentPropTypes = {
   foo: PropTypes.any,
};

const SecondComponentPropTypes = {
   bar: PropTypes.any,
};

function MyComponent({ foo, bar }) { ... }

MyComponent.propTypes = Object.assign({}, SecondComponentPropTypes, FirstComponentProptypes);
```

Comment: What if the FirstComponentPropTypes  has a "bar" property like the second one, but required? Then the merge will overlap the definition right? It is not an OR at all (?) just a merge of objects.

Comment: In JSDoc for example, you can do something like: @type {React.FC<FirstComponentProps | SecondComponentProps>} I am just looking for something like this but with the 'prop-types' library.

Comment: If `bar` is required in `SecondComponent` but not inside `FirstComponent`, I will get warnings. So to handle this, what I was doing was creating another propTypes object for the generic component, with the union of all the properties, but marking them as not required.